# Please help explain this for loops that uses the len function in a range function

Tags: python, for-loop, range

I am a beginner on Python 3.0 and recently learning via YouTube. I'm stuck at this particular part of one video explaining about 'for loops' which starts from 0:00 to 3:10.

(Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVyWLmQ0QYA&t=190s&ab_channel=CSDojo)

The instructor basically shows how to print elements in a list based on their index number. The code shown is as follows:

```
a = ['apple', 'banana', 'republic']
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        print(a[i])
```

The output for the code would be:

```
apple
banana
banana
republic
republic
republic
```

I don't really understand how the whole code executes, any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: which part is unclear?

Comment: the whole code, sorry im just a beginner

Comment: You could try to run this code on this site -https://pythontutor.com/  to inspect each step execution.

Comment: @DanielHao hey thanks for the tip, im understanding it little by little now

Comment: You can even go inserting this print line after 2nd for-loop: ` print(f' i={i}, j={j} ')`  and try to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you step through each iteration it becomes clear:

- In the first iteration, i = 0 and range of j is just 1 so it prints 'apple' 1 time.
- Next iteration, i = 1 and range of j is 2 so it prints 'banana' 2 times
- Finally, in the third iteration i = 2 and range of j is 3 so it prints 'republic' 3 times.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to understand your code is to print the value of counter in loops (which are i and j here)

What can learn from this particular exemple is (I added some specificity of python):

-You can see that len(a) return 3 which is the number of elements in the list. However the first item of the list is a[0] and the last a[2]

-In python, you can call negative index, a[-1] will return "republic". Note that this is not working for the majority of programmation languages.

-Last important notion here is that your loop begin with index 0 and stop when index is >= to the specified range. As exemple:

```
for k in range(3)
```

k will take 0, 1,2 but not 3